# Print the same variable (n) with changing meaning on the same line

Tags: python-3.x

I have to "encrypt" a small text by moving each letter a bit. Capital letters should stay capital, lowercase should stay lowercase. For example if I move "aBc" by 1 I should get "bCd". All other signs such as "!","*" etc. as well as numbers should stay the same. 
I should save the new text in a variable called encoded but I cannot for the life of me figure out how. At the moment it just prints everything in one line but the system thats correcting my software won't accept this solution, as the variable encode should already be "bCd" and not just the print. Can anybody help?

I'm a newbie so I haven't really tried a lot...

```
# The following variables will be provided by the grading environment, you
# can access them without declaration. You can also freely adopt the values
# to play around with your solution. However, you must not set them to
# fixed values outside of the "if" or the automated grading will break.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    plain_text = input()
    shift_by = 1

idx = 2
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ABC = "ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for n in plain_text:
    if n in plain_text:
        old = ord(n)
        if (old >= 97 and old <= 122) or (old <= 90 and old >= 65):
            new = old+shift_by
            if new < 65 and old <= 90 and old >= 65:
                n = chr(91-(65-new))
            elif new > 90 and old <= 90 and old >= 65:
                n = chr((new-91)+65)
            elif new < 97 and old >= 97 and old <= 122:
                n = chr(123-(new-97))
            elif new > 122 and old <= 122 and old >= 97:
                n = chr((new-123)+97)
            else:
                n = chr(new)
        else:
            n = n
        encoded = n
        print(encoded, end ="")
    idx +=1
```

the expected results would be that encoded is "bCd". At the moment thats just the print. The error from the correcting software is as follows

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/src/public/tests.py", line 28, in test_case0

self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

AssertionError: 'b, C, d#!' != '!'

- b, C, d#!
- !

Comment: It doesn't look like you use `abc` or `ABC`, but notice they are different lengths.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot. But abc and ABC are pretty much useless not sure why I still have them in there.

Comment: The auto-grader might be failing because it expects the entire result to be in `encoded`? You are only storing one letter at a time, printing it, and then overwriting `encoded`. If that's the case, then set `encoded` to an empty string at the beginning, and then add the encoded letter  to `encoded` during every iteration: `encoded += n`. (I have no idea if the rest of your program is working correctly though)

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my problem! The rest works alright thanks!